# Is there an F# equivalent to the TPL Parallel.Invoke?

Tags: f#, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

Is there an F# equivalent to the TPL Parallel.Invoke? So far, all  i have come across is task factory for explicit task control but i am having problems profiling it.

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with using `Parallel.Invoke` *from* F#? One of the best features of F# is that you can re-use all of the functionality available in the .NET Base Class Libraries (BCL).

To simplify things, I'd probably create a little function to map an array of F# functions into an array of `Action` delegates, like this:

```
/// Wraps each F# in a System.Action delegate.
let funcsAsActions (funcs : (unit -> unit)[]) : System.Action[] =
    funcs |> Array.map (fun f -> System.Action f)
```

Then, you can just pass the array returned by `funcsAsActions` to `Parallel.Invoke`.

Comment: What's wrong with `funcs |> Array.Parallel.iter (fun f -> f ())`? Mapping to `Action`s first strikes me as pointless.

Comment: @ildjarn Nothing's wrong with that solution either. OP just asked about using `Parallel.Invoke`. There's also an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783942%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Parallel.Invoke` which accepts a `ParallelOptions` so you can tune the execution behavior (which you can't do with `Array.Parallel.iter`).

Comment: @ildjarn You really should post your comment as an answer